# Dynamic Tabs using Dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, telerik

How can I load dynamic tabs for one or more datasets? I need some help fetching/mapping the dataset table names on a tab.

Comment: Did you tried anything? Show your effort first.. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Use AjaxTabContainer and assign the name and data inside tabs programitaclly from code behind. There are several functions provided in the AjaxTabContainer class.

Comment: my problem is i want to create a dynamic tab form on the bases of dataset tables e.g dataset having 3 tables a,b c and i want "tab a", "tab2" so on